# Find the real caller in method call

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I have a struct like this:

```
type Parent struct {
    example string
}
func (p *Parent) GetMyAttr() {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(p).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {
        p := typ.Field(i)
        if !p.Anonymous {
            fmt.Println(p.Name, ":", p.Type)
        }
    }
}
```

And if I have another struct like this:

```
type Child struct {
    Parent
    another string
}
```

call GetTypeOfMe() in child like this

```
ch := Child{Parent{"example"},"another"}
ch.GetMyAttr()
```

is always return  `example : string` .
Is this possible to get Child struct in Parent struct with reflection?

Full code is here http://play.golang.org/p/ej4Xh_V2J1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work like this, `reflect.TypeOf(p).Elem()` will always return `Parent` you have 2 options, either implement `GetMyAttr` for each child or use a generic function [like](http://play.golang.org/p/7qxp1i2-BN) :

```
func GetAttr(i interface{}) {
    typ := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i)).Type()
    fmt.Println(typ)
    for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {
        p := typ.Field(i)
        fmt.Println(p.Name, ":", p.Type)

    }
}
```

Comment: I accept this, since there is no better option for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, since you operate on a `*Parent`, not a `*Child`.
This would "work" ([play.golang](http://play.golang.org/p/QuywV1VO2b))

```
func (p *Child) GetMyAttr() {...
```

would output:

```
Parent : main.Parent
another : string
```

A `Parent` doesn't know about the `struct` which might embed it, so the reflection operates only on `Parent` struct.

You see a similar issue with "[Go Reflection with Embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10255926/6309)", which uses `interface{}` to get to *all* the struct passed in parameter.

Comment: I have more than one child, re-write this method for every one of them is not my option.

Comment: @fzerorubigd I understand. I was just pointing why this wasn't working.